# (index):126 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 0 is neither

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, websocket

I am seeing this error

> (index):126 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'close' on
>   'WebSocket': The code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 0
>   is neither.
>       at WebSocket. (http://localhost:3701/:126:14)

the code I am using was:

```
  const createConnection = () => {

    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3702');

    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
      console.log('connection made to server:', event);
    });

    socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
      console.log('connection closed:', event);
      socket.close(0, 'unknown');   // THIS CAUSED ERROR
      createConnection();
    });


    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      console.log('ws client received message:', event);
      location.reload();
    });

  };
```

anyone know what the error is about?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered changing

```
socket.close(0, 'unknown');
```

to

```
socket.close(1000, 'unknown');
```

Comment: yep that didn't work, I am looking for why more than how to quick fix

Comment: @MrCholo have you read the documentation on WebSocket.close() ?

Comment: can you link to the documentation? I will accept your answer in that case thanks

Comment: You can check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close but I am on mobile right now so its hard to tell if this is same one I was looking at before

Comment: this works for me :). but mdn states that you can also call close without specifying a code e.g. .close("some reason") witch (for some reason) didn't worked for me on chrome